# Deploying Node Apps via Gitolite and post-receive hook

Tags: node.js, unix, deployment, permissions, gitolite

I'm trying to get a fairly simple deploy process going for a Node app using Gitolite. I have Gitolite setup and working on my server, and I'm able to push to it fine.

Gitolite is running under a user called `git`, and I've setup a `node` user that I'm hoping to use to run the Node app.

My plan is to push the Node app to Gitolite, and then use a post-receive hook script to move the app files to the directory where the app lives, in this case `/var/local/node-apps/my-node-app/`. I created the Node app folder like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/local/node-apps/my-node-app
sudo chown node /var/local/node-apps/my-node-app
```

The problem is that I'm a Unix noob and I haven't got my head round file/folder permissions and wotnot.

`/var/local/node-apps` (and also `/var/local/node-apps/my-node-app`) is owned by the `node` user, so when the `git` user tries to checkout to this location I get a bunch of permission denied errors. The command I'm using in the post-receive is:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/local/node-apps/my-node-app git checkout -f
```

And I get errors like this:

```
remote: error: git checkout-index: unable to create file XXXX (Permission denied)
remote: fatal: cannot create directory at 'XXXX': Permission denied
```

What's the best way to resolve this? Do I need to grant the `git` user password-less sudo rights to `su` as the `node` user? Or can this be somehow fixed by changing groups and folder permissions? Or a different approach entirely? I'm lost!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sudo would certainly work, you have one example at "[post-receive hook permission denied “unable to create file” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211950/post-receive-hook-permission-denied-unable-to-create-file-error)", wrapping the git commands in a script.

> Changed post-receive to:

```
sudo sh /usr/local/sbin/prgetsimpleappscom
```

> Changed sudoers with visudo

```
git ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh /usr/local/sbin/prgetsimpleappscom
```

The other approach would be a cron job as `node` user regularly fetching and (if there are new commit) pulling in the destination repo.

Comment: Thanks!

In the example you referenced the guy basically fixed his problem by adding to the sudoers file. Are there any security implications to consider with his approach?

Comment: @Wintamute the script (referenced in the `suoders` file) needs to be controlled by root (in order to ensure it cannot be changed to do anything else than what it is supposed to do). Beside that, you have the usual pros and cons of using sudo: http://serverfault.com/questions/140633/security-issue-of-linux-sudo-command

Comment: Ah, I see, makes sense. He actually appends three lines to `sudoers` in his example. `git ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/prgetsimpleappscom`, `git ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh` and `git ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh /usr/local/sbin/prgetsimpleappscom`. Are all three necessary?

Comment: @Wintamute I din't test directly, but I believe they might be needed, in order for the script (and the git commands) to execute properly as sudo.

Comment: I just did a quick test and everything seemed to work with just the final line `git ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh /usr/local/sbin/prgetsimpleappscom`. Am I right in thinking that that final line locks down the `git` user to only being able to run the `/bin/sh` command as root without a password *and* only with the argument `/usr/local/sbin/prgetsimpleappscom`? In which case it seems like a good idea to minimise the changes to `sudoers` to just this (from a security perspective)?

Comment: @Wintamute yes, you are right. In this case, minimizing the number of authorized commands in the `sudoers` is safer.