# deploying a website/webapp via git/gitolite permissions error

Tags: git, unix, version-control, gitolite, githooks

I've setup a development/testing server where developers can push repositories to a remote repo/webserver via gitolite/git.
On the repository site everything works well and developers can use the server however:

**Problem:**

I want to deploy the code to an apache documentroot (chown'd apache:apcahe and chmod'd 755). [I am following these instructions](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) and when edit my post-receive hook as describe like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "deploying to DocumentRoot"
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.com git checkout -f
```

however now when I run git push from my local repo I get permissions errors like:

```
error: git checkout-index: unable to create file .gitignore (Permission denied)
error: git checkout-index: unable to create file .htaccess (Permission denied)
```

And my document root is empty...The post-receive hook is running as the user 'gitolite' (not sure whether that's important).

gitolite is already in the sudoers list so I want to run something like:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.com sudo git checkout -f
```

but this doesn't seem to work either, I want to avoid [calling a separate shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481197/deploying-node-apps-via-gitolite-and-post-receive-hook/12481490#12481490) if possible.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: Any possibility to ensure `gitolite` user is in the same group than the `apache` account?

Comment: just added the 
    gitolite
user to the apache group and ran post-recieve hook with sudo now I get:
    fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born  -- ps: how do you do the highlighting in comments?

Comment: thanks to @VonC I fixed this but the answer was to do "sudo GIT_WORK_TREE=..... git checkout -f"

Comment: By the way, using `\`` allows you to highlight within comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure the git account is in the same group than the apache account.
(Or you need to go back to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481197/deploying-node-apps-via-gitolite-and-post-receive-hook/12481490#12481490) that you want to avoid)

You report this works:

```
 sudo GIT_WORK_TREE=..... git checkout -f
```

But with a bare repo, you could also see get:

```
 fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
```

(I wouldn't recommend trying to make your gitolite-managed *bare* repo a non-bare one as in this [blog post](http://www.deanoj.co.uk/programming/git/using-git-and-a-post-receive-hook-script-for-auto-deployment/)

```
git config core.worktree /home/user/myproject
git config core.bare false
git config receive.denycurrentbranch ignore
```

)

I prefer making sure `/var/www/www.example.com` directory is a git repo, in which you can pull, instead of trying to checkout.
So the hook I like is more:

```
cd /var/www/www.example.com
git --git-dir=/var/www/www.example.com/.git --git-work-tree=/var/www/www.example.com pull
```

(with `origin`, the remote name which is used by default by `git pull`, refering to the gitolite bare repo)

Comment: nice.. it turned out that what I was doing worked perfectly except that (a) permissions were a problem. (b) sudo was in the wrong place. Many thanks VonC