# gitolite/git clone no overwriting previous version

Tags: git, unix, version-control, gitolite

My [struggles with git/gitolite continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407350/deploying-a-website-webapp-via-git-gitolite-permissions-error). I am trying to setup a means of deploying a website/webapp by using the `post-receive` hook.

basically I have a remote repo which is then cloned into a `DocumentRoot` for apache to serve.
My `post-receive` hook looks like this:

```
document_root=/path/to/document/root
echo "deploying to web directory"
sudo GIT_WORK_TREE=$document_root git checkout -f
sudo chown -R apache:apache $document_root
```

Everything works great -- for the first deployment, however git seems to ignore any changes thereafter.
If I `add` files then `git push` they go to my remote repo but are not cloned into the `DocumentRoot` and no errors are given.

Can anyone think of what might be going wrong?

Comment: did you tried a `sudo GIT_WORK_TREE=$document_root git checkout -f master`? (specifying the branch you want to checkout)

Comment: I'm not sure if you know this but you are a GOD amongst men VonC!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the branch explicitly should work better:

```
sudo GIT_WORK_TREE=$document_root git checkout -f master
```

(That supposes you did push new commits to the `master` branch, of course)