# Do an automatic pull request after pushing to server

Tags: git, hook, gitlab

I have installed gitlab on a vps server which is also my remote for committing my local changes.

When i commit and push to the server (git@domain.com:root/project.git), the code will be updated.

On my vps i have this workflow:

```
- var/www/
    - project (created through git clone git@domain.com:root/project.git)
        - Files within the project
```

When i do a push to the server, i want to let the server automatic pull the changes from gitlab. I also did a try with post-update hooks, but that doesn't work.

Do i have to create a bare repo ? Or did i forget something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

project.git *is* a bare repo, so if you have access to the gitlab server, you can go to `~git/repositories/root/project.git/hooks` and add your `post-receive` hook in order to force a deployment.

See an example in "[deploying a website/webapp via git/gitolite permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411542/6309)" for instance.

Comment: Thankyou! Do i need to do this for every project? Because i use gitlab for my customer websites

Comment: @MattDice for every repository, yes.