# A hook that let `pull` from VPS when I `push` to Bitbucket

Tags: git

I'm managing my wordpress template in Bitbucket.

Each time I `push` the theme, I must log in my VPS server and `pull` the repo.
I want to do it automatically.

I found a solution if I run git deamon myown.
[Do an automatic pull request after pushing to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569581/do-an-automatic-pull-request-after-pushing-to-server)

But I want to use Bitbucket because it works as a backup also.

I found a Document about bitbucket's hook, but I could't find how to do it.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks

Could anyone show me a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a very basic tutorial on this:

- http://jan1337z.blogspot.de/2013/04/post-hook-for-git-bitbucketorg.html

this basic steps are:

1. Create a Read-Only access to the Repository with a public-key pair.
2. Add the public key as a deployment key to your repository
   (Repository -> Settings -> Deployment keys)
3. Pull your Repository to your WebServer via SSH
4. Change ownership of the git-folder (you pulled) to www-data (as this
   is the apache2 user)
5. Create a public accessable php script that executed a git pull
6. Place a POST-hook to your php-pull-script on your Server (Repository
   -> admin -> Hooks -> POST)

*Cant find admin?*
while you are on your repository (on bitbucket) its the gearwheel in the top right. Either click on it or type 'r' and then 'a'.

Basic PHP script to make the pull:

> ```
> <?php
>     $output = shell_exec('git pull');
>     echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
> ?>
> ```

I had this running just to proof that it is possible. Improve it :)

How to create a deployment key (step 2):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I couldn't find `Repository -> admin`. Where is it?

Comment: while you are on your repository (on bitbucket) there is a gearwheel in the top right. Either click on it or type 'r' and then 'a'. (thats admin)

Comment: Thanks I found it, great!

Comment: Bitbucket has changed a lot now - this answer is not working anymore

Comment: I am not able to find the deployment key option anymore. Any help?