# Git post-receive permissions

Tags: git, githooks, mediatemple

I have a git repository setup on Media template gs hosting. I'm using a post-receive hook to deploy my application when I push to the origin. The hook runs fine, but if I try and make it update a working copy it fails to due to a permissions error.
This is my post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/path/to/workingcopy/ git checkout -f
```

When the git hook runs it appears to run as the user 'me%mydomain.com' but the owner of my working files is 'mydomain.com'

I've tried setting git config --global user.email "mydomain.com". But it does not seem to effect it.

Is it possible to make the git hook run the correct user?

Answer (score 1):

Ah I found the issue: I had my remote `origin` setting as

```
me@mydomain.com@mydomain.com:/home/data/git/repo.git
```

instead of:

```
serveradmin@mydomain.com@mydomain.com:/home/data/git/repo.git
```

`serveradmin` has access to all files in MT sharing hosting.
Additionally I could of applied sub-ftp permissions to '`me@mydomain`' in the MT user preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a similar approach as the one described in "[deploying a website/webapp via git/gitolite permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407350/deploying-a-website-webapp-via-git-gitolite-permissions-error)", and:

- add `git` user to the `sudoers` file.
- do a
  `sudo GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/path/to/workingcopy/ git checkout -f`