# Setting up a git and multiple environments for expression engine

Tags: git, testing, development-environment, expressionengine

Hi everyone, I'm a complete noob with git and I have some questions on setting up an environment.

I have an ubuntu linux server on which i have setup the following sites as vhosts:

www.mydomain : production environment
 stage.mydomain : staging environment for client approval tests
 dev.mydomain : development environment for testing new code

i also have MAMP setup locally as a local dev environment.

What I would like to be able to do is to use the www.mydomain as a repo, then clone to stage, from stage to dev and then from dev to local. I have done this sucessfully already.

When I am happy with my work on local, i add/commit files, then push back to the dev for server specific testing.

Now I have managed to do a remote push back to the dev.mydomain without errors, but when I check the files, I find these haven't been updated to include my adds/commits.

Can some one help out? Am I misunderstanding how this works, if so how can I apply the changes to the dev.mydomain filesystem for testing?

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have managed to do a remote push back to the `dev.mydomain` without errors, but when I check the files, I find these haven't been updated to include my adds/commits.

Pushing to an [upstream remote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) repo means:

- pushing to a **[bare repo](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html)** (meaning there is no files to see! There is no working tree in a remote repo)
- or pushing to a **non-bare repo**, but in that case you can only do so *without error* if you are pushing a branch which **is not checked out** in that remote repo.
  Which means *none* of the currently visible files on that upstream repo are modified.
  That is the all point of allowing that push: you are sure there is no discrepancies between that checked out branch HEAD and the HEAD you are pushing. The problem is detailed in "[`git push` error: refusing to update checked out branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14879452/6309)".

So I would recommend:

- setting up a bare dev repo,
- pushing to it,
- and having a post-receive hook going to a second dev repo (this time non-bare) and pulling from the (updated) bare repo.
  See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411542/6309).

Comment: Thanks alot for the clarification, I was getting mixed up on how to deploy with multiple environments! This has cleared it up for me now, thanks!