# Permissions with Git Post-Receive

Tags: git, permissions, vps

I have setup git locally and on my server and created a 'post-receive' so that when I do a push to the live server it should then checkout to the virtual hosts directory of the website.

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/domainname/public_html/ git checkout -f
```

However, when I try to do my push, it goes out the master successfully but I get permission denied errors when trying to create those files on my server web root.

e.g. `remote: error: unable to create file index.php (Permission denied)`

These errors actually make sense to me due to the way I have setup my server. I disabled root access and created a new user that is added to the sudoers through visudo - I then set up SSH keys for this user. I use this user for pushing out my git changes to the server.

The issue is, I believe, that this user that I connect to push doesn't have the rights to write to the virtual hosts directory. All my files in these folders are owned by www-data (my nginx user) with the same group.

What is the solution? Create another user with SSH keys to connect with just for git that has higher permissions or is there a way to grant the post-receive sudo like abilities?

Apologies for the very long winded question but wanted to be absolutely clear with what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your repo is created with the `--shared` option (see "[Change GIT repository to shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268560/change-git-repository-to-shared)"), that would allow users from the *same group* to access and write.

Is there any way you can group those different users in the same group?
A bit as what is mentioned in "[Git unable to create file permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12077758/6309)" same group.
Or sudo access, as explained in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11211950/6309), changing the sudoers:

```
 git ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/prgetsimpleappscom
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. To be clear though, I have no issues pushing to the repo on the server, its when the post-receive tries to copy over the files to the web root that I get issues. The files there are owned by www-data so that the web server can write to them / run them correctly. e.g. add plugins from the admin.

Comment: Further, its the user that I use to push remote using ssh that doesn't have the rights to copy and overwrite files in the web root. I feel like I am overlooking something obvious!!

Comment: @bbish007 the only thing that can help (beside executing the command with sudo right) is for that user to be in the same group as the group of the files in web root.

Comment: Actually something in the last link might have nailed it, will confirm asap.git ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/prgetsimpleappscom

Comment: Thanks, yeah I have already tried adding the user to the same group as the group of files in web root. In this case, www-data, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @bbish007 ok, and what about the sudoers option (that I have detailed in the edited answer)?

Comment: I have gone down the sudo no password option for it and it solves what I was trying to achieve. Thanks very much for all your effort on this.