# post-receive /var/www/html denied

Tags: wordpress, git, hook, git-push, git-post-receive

My username (let’s call it `my_name`) belongs to the Apache group which is owner of `var/www/html` directory, sub-directories and files contained within.

In that directory I installed Wordpress. Directories and files permissions are set to 0775 (yeah, I know the files should have 644, but it is not a factor for now).

Well, my username has writing permissions indeed, because I am able to create new files or directories, as well as delete them, by using SSH terminal or WinSCP.

The problem comes up when I run a post-receive hook of a bare git repository, no matter if by running the script or by pushing changes from the local working repository.
In any scenario, the post-receive hook does not work because of permission denied. Really strange and I cannot understand why.

Could you help me please?

**Edit:**
This is the output of `ls -alrth ~/git/devsite.git/hooks` directory:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 name apache  896 Apr  2 22:41 commit-msg.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 name apache  727 Apr  7 09:09 post-receive
-rwxrwxr-x 1 name apache  189 Apr  2 22:41 post-update.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 name apache  398 Apr  2 22:41 pre-applypatch.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 name apache 1704 Apr  2 22:41 pre-commit.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 name apache 1239 Apr  2 22:41 prepare-commit-msg.sample
-rw-rw-r-- 1 name apache 1348 Apr  2 22:41 pre-push.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 name apache 4951 Apr  2 22:41 pre-rebase.sample
-rwxrwxr-x 1 name apache 3611 Apr  2 22:41 update.sample
```

This is the post-receive script:

```
#!/bin/sh
TARGET=/var/www/html/wp-content
GIT_DIR=/home/name/git/devsite.git

#run 'post-receive' hook
git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Try again after a

```
cd /path/tp/bare/repo
git config core.sharedRepository true
```

I mentioned it before in "[Permissions with Git Post-Receive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15861652/6309)".

In the OP's instance, the `post-receive` script is not placed properly: it should be in `~/git/devsite.git/hooks`, not `~/git/devsite.git`.

Comment: not working. `/var/www/html` has `apache:apache` as owner/group, the `post-receive` bash script has been run as `my_username` but it does not work. Incredible!

Comment: @R99Photography Can you edit your question with the output of `ls -alrth /path/to/post-receive/parent/folder`?

Comment: you have the details you had asked me. Night.

Comment: @R99Photography I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Post-receive is already in hooks. I don’t know what is that., but not the script I am trying to run

Comment: @R99Photography So what does ls -alrth of the hooks folder look like?

Comment: here we are with the hooks

Comment: @R99Photography OK, looks good. "name" should be able to execute that script. Does it start with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang directive?

Comment: added the post-receive bash script

Comment: @R99Photography Can you, just for testing, replace the script content (after the first line) with `id -a` and `pwd`? Would that work or still generate a "permission denied"?

Comment: Sorry but did not understand you, what should I have to edit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168471/discussion-between-vonc-and-r99photography).

Comment: @R99Photography Replace the script content with those two lines: simplify in order to understand where the permission denied is coming from.